# Remove inline styles from innerHtml using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am parsing a web page to return all the unique sentences on the page, each with a minimum of two words. It almost works.  The following appears as one sentence in  the page however my code is dropping the text in the `<b></b>` tags. How do I remove the inline style/tags to return the sentence as it appears in the browser with the text in the bold tags or any other inline style like strong tags?

Currently it returns NHL Playoffs as one line of text and then Takeaways: Sharks beat Penguins for first Stanley Cup Final win as the second sentence when it is really just one sentence.

```
<span class="titletext"><b>NHL Playoffs</b> Takeaways: Sharks beat Penguins for first Stanley Cup Final win</span>
```

Here is my asp.net vb.net code (c# solution is fine).

```
Public Shared Function validateIsMoreThanOneWord(input As String, numberWords As Integer) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return (input.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length >= numberWords)
    End Function

    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load

        Try

            Dim html = New HtmlDocument()
            html.LoadHtml(New WebClient().DownloadString("http://news.google.ca/nwshp?hl=en&ei=4H1UV7-NNOfCjwTAl4bABw&ved=0EKkuCAkoBw"))

            Dim root = html.DocumentNode

            Dim myList As New List(Of String)()

            For Each node As HtmlNode In root.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Text AndAlso n.ParentNode.Name <> "script" AndAlso n.ParentNode.Name <> "style" AndAlso n.ParentNode.Name <> "css")

                If Not node.HasChildNodes Then
                    Dim text As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(node.InnerText)

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) Then
                        If validateIsMoreThanOneWord(text.Trim(), 2) Then
                            myList.Add(text.Trim())
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            'remove dups from array and other stuff
            Dim q As String() = myList.Distinct().ToArray()

            For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(q)
                Response.Write(q(i).Trim() & "<br/>")
            Next

            Response.Write(q.Count)


        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Hope you can shed some light on a solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping over all root descendant nodes which parent is not `<script>`, nor `<style>` nor `css`, you will indeed treat every child node from .titleText as a different piece of text.

What you want is to retrieve the `InnerText` of each `.titletext` entry.

The following is what I would do in C#, you can get the idea of what you need to do.

```
    HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
    var htmlDoc = w.Load("http://news.google.ca/nwshp?hl=en&ei=4H1UV7-NNOfCjwTAl4bABw&ved=0EKkuCAkoBw");
    var textTitles = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='titletext']");

//for testing purposes
        foreach (var textTitle in textTitles)
            Console.WriteLine(textTitle.InnerText);
```

Comment: Hi Veverke, I am crawling a page (not necessarily this one) and do not know if the div will have this type of formatting, but if it does then I would like to return just the text. Not sure if this is possible with the code I have?

Comment: the `InnerText ` of the `HtmlNode` object, right ? I don't see how you can extract data if you do not know where from. In case you know what where to extract the data from - say, in our example, span nodes classed with 'titletext', then you would get *just the text* with the code above (you will obviously not print the lines but do whatever else you want with them). The code above will not do it ?